# Should I reinstall the YCM (YouCompleteMe) plug-in after :PluginUpdate?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-vundle

I have the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) plugin installed. *After the `:PluginUpdate` has been invoked should I repeat the installation process of the `YouCompleteMe` plugin ?* I am 99% sure I should as I think the `:PluginUpdate` just "pulls" the actual version: for some plugins it may be sufficient but I doubt the `YCM` is one of them.

Comment: BTW, the purpose of this site is to ask questions and get answers. Please don't apologize for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should run `install.py` (plus options) again. It pulls several other repos and compiles things.

It may not be necessary, depending on the nature of the changes.
YCM's [own doc](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#quick-start-installing-all-completers-1) says:

> Remember: YCM is a plugin with a compiled component. If you update YCM using Vundle and the ycm_core library APIs have changed (happens rarely), YCM will notify you to recompile it. You should then rerun the install process.

To err on the side of caution, install it again.

I see you are using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), so the last paragraph may not be for you. With [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) you can define a post-update action like this:

```
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe', {'do': './install.py --clangd-completer --ts-completer'}
```

It will automate the whole process. Other plugin managers may have similar features.

Comment: Cool ! Thank you.